# What is the current Portuguese word for 'hostel'?

Tags: tradução-inglês

EN:

Until recently, the Portuguese word for hostel was 'albergue', and youth hostel would be 'pousada da juventude'.
But, in this June, 2016, I visited many hostels in Lisbon, and the Portuguese people, like me, working in the hostel, no longer use the term 'alberge', simply named as hostel, although the conversation was set in Portuguese.

Is the word 'albergue' still the formal translation for 'hostel', or has been dropped in favor of 'hostel'.

What about in informal speech?

PT:
Qual é a atual tradução para a palavra inglesa 'hostel'?
Tradicionalmente era 'albergue', e pousada da juventude para 'youth hostel'.
Mas, em Junho de 2016 visitei muitos 'hostels' em Lisboa, a palavra utilizada foi sempre 'hostel', nunca utilizando a palavra 'albergue'.
A palavra 'albergue' ainda é a tradução formal, ou já foi abandonada em favor de 'hostel'.
E em discurso informal?

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question.  You went to Portugal and everyone said hostel. So.....

Comment: The data that I collected is limited only to people working in hostels, from such data I can't extrapolate the usage on the overall population. 
Therefore your claim is not true.

Comment: Are you interested in answers for Portugal, or for the Portuguese language as a whole?

Comment: Em Portugal o uso quase generalizado de "hostel", especialmente nos jornais, revistas e televisão,  é bastante recente, não tem mais do que dez anos.

Answer (score 5):

**"albergue" is the word for "hostel" in pt-BR.**

In Brazil, **the word "albergue" is still current usage**.  When my daughters travelled with their classmates to Rio Grande do Sul, they stayed in "albergues". There is this old bed-and-breakfast chain called "Albergue da Juventude" ( http://www.alberguedajuventude.com.br/ ) Any youth who enrolls, gets a personal card and information about lodgings all over the world.

The English word "hostel" has also been used in Brazil so that foreign tourists can understand what "albergue" means.

Comment: From the time, I spend in Brazil, but it was many years ago, the people working in hostels, called their establishment "hostal", nevertheless it was again words use only by people working there, and many years ago, just like the current data that I hold.   
Thank you for the information provided, I thought in Brazil, it was used "hostel" or "hostal" similar to the usage of other assimilated English words.

Answer (score 3):

No Brasil é bastante comum o uso da palavra *hostel* para se referir a este tipo de estabelecimento, sendo usado, p.ex. no nome de [sites que fazem reservas](http://hihostelbrasil.com.br) ou no [nome de estabelecimentos](http://www.solar63hostel.com.br).

Talvez seja uma percepção pessoal, mas *albergue* me remete imediatamente ao estabelecimento onde mendigos se recolhem à noite (como pode ser visto [no 2o significado no Dicio](http://www.dicio.com.br/albergue/)). Também pode se referir ao [estabelecimento prisional](http://www.conjur.com.br/2011-out-04/condenado-cumprir-pena-casa-quando-falta-albergue) onde detentos do regime aberto cumprem parte de sua pena.

Comment: Em Brasília, pelo menos coloquialmente, usa-se "albergue" em ambas acepções (hotel barato, abrigo para desvalidos). "Pousada", assim como "albergue da juventude") refere-se apenas à primeira acepção, e "abrigo" à segunda (e a muitas outras, mas nunca à primeira). "*Hostel*" nunca vi usado; talvez seja algum modismo novo, ou só se encontre na forma escrita. Na minha opinião, é o típico empréstimo desnecessário, "*meté a la bête*"...

Comment: Em Portugal, nos sites de reserva, também estão listados como "hostels", no entanto a minha questão era no sentido em determinar como a população portuguesa os identificava na linguagem comum.

Comment: Hostel tem sido usado pelo menos em São Paulo, talvez por causa desse outro sentido de albergue que você mencionou. Em outras partes do Brasil pode não ser o caso, como indicam o comentário do Luís Henrique e a resposta do Centaurus.

Comment: Hotel barato é pousada, mas tem de lembrar que pousada pode ser um hotel turístico também. Albergue realmente remete a locais às vezes precários; geralmente baratos, ou gratuitos para desamparados. Algumas imagens de albergue no google tem até várias beliches em um quarto.

Answer (score 3):

Traditionally, Portugal used the word "pensão" for "hostel" in the sense that hostels are cheaper places. Brazil uses "albergue".

These days, in Portugal, the term "hostel" is being used along with "pensão" as well but there is a difference: both are cheap but the hostels usually have shared rooms while a "pensão" does not.

Comment: The English word that matches the style and category for a "pensão" is "guesthouse", although I do remember seeing a "pensão" in Coimbra with a sign underneath with the word "hostel".   
Today, there is a proliferation of hostels in Lisbon, I visited more than 30 recently, many of them completely the portuguese word, and their style and services offered are different from a "pensão".

Comment: Yeap, it's not unusual for a "pensão" to offer rooms for 6 people... and being cheap makes it quite similar to hostel. In Portugal, you won't see the word "albergue" being used for hostels but you might see a "pensão" operating quite in a similar way as a hostel. A hostel in Portugal will most likely be called a hostel and conser its english form.

Comment: pensão ou pensionato geralmente é uma casa de uma família que aluga quartos, pelo menos no Brasil.